# Htaccess Redirect directory to another but allow the main folder URL to stay the same

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, friendly-url

We are currently using the below .htaccess code to redirect /artist/* to /artists/* which works well however, we need the URL /artist/ to remain available and not redirect through to /artists/ is this possible with .htaccess? We'd like to avoid a PHP based redirect if possible.

```
RewriteRule ^artist/(.*)$ /artists/$1 [R=301,NC,L]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to change URL in your browser means you don't want to redirect and only want to rewrite to different URL then try following(we need to remove `R` flag from rules. Also this rule considers that you have `/artists` in your root directory if that's not the case then remove its starting slash in Rule.

```
RewriteRule ^artist/(.*)/?$ /artists/$1 [NC,L]
```

Comment: We did want to redirect it but just the sub pages, your code works perfect when we include the R 301 flag. Thanks!

Comment: @HarryRobinson, Your welcome, cheers and happy learning; keep posting and keep sharing on this great forum.